# What is the proper word for a surname from a previous marriage?

Tags: single-word-requests, forms-of-address

Let's say that Jane Doe marries David Jones, divorces him and then marries John Smith. During the first marriage, we say that she is Jane Jones née Doe and the same (Jane Smith née Doe) during the second marriage, but if we want to denote the intermediary relationship, what is the right word for this?

Jane Smith (née Jane Jones née Jane Smith) doesn't seem right because 'née' means 'born' and she wasn't born Jane Jones.

My best guess is to just use 'AKA' for all the previous marriages and birth surnames: Jane Smith (AKA Jane Jones AKA Jane Doe) or perhaps 'formerly' instead of 'AKA'.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is *AKA*?  Is it a foreign (to the monoglot English speaker) word meaning *née*?

Comment: When Elizabeth Taylor celebrated her eighth marriage, I don't think anyone referred to her as Elizabeth Fortensky, formerly Warner, Burton (twice), Fisher, Todd, Wilding, and Hilton née Taylor. I would think referring to her previous husbands would have been considered bad taste and disrespectful to the new husband but those were other times.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - 'Also known as' - but it refers to people using an alias. If you need to mention a woman's former married name, _formerly_ seems the appropriate choice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: This is for encyclopedic work. I care about accuracy. I don't care about "bad taste".

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks! I've accepted DanM87's same answer below.

Comment: I did also add that those were other times. Accuracy? Perhaps but you suggested AKA, also known as, that's not accurate.

Comment: @KateBunting, thanks for the clarification. Given what AKA means, it might be entirely the wrong term to use, Oft-Married Jane might not be also known by any of her previous husbands surnames, she may be known solely by the current one. As Mari-Lou A points out.

Comment: Well, you have certainly proved your point, **I don't care about "bad taste"**.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Because someone else's sense of social conformity isn't relevant to what I'm working on and what motivated me to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's necessary to clarify the identity of who you're talking about, I would say *formerly* is the correct usage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).